# can't save text from a uitextfield into nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I can't get my UITextField to store the data that I enter into a NSString variable. It is always saying that it is nil. I can't seem to figure out why. I have tried with format and without a format.

```
NSString *payee, *date, *description, *amount, *tip, *total;

payee = [_payeeName.text copy];
date = _dateField.text;
description = _itemDescrip.text;
amount = _itemPrice.text;
tip = _tip.text;
total = _totalPrice.text;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

I have tried with the copy and without the copy.

Comment: Is payeeName nil?  Did you connect the UITextField in the storyboard to the outlet payeeName?

Comment: Have you verified that `_payeeName` isn't `nil`?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to check for that. This is a new language for me.

Comment: You can follow this link :: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/how-to-collect-text-input-using-uitextfield/